# Unity3d reloads in browser after changing display property of its html container

Tags: jquery, html, css, unity-game-engine, unityscript

We use Unity3D web plugin and interact with unity container on html page through UnityScript object.

Sometimes if we reached specific conditions we need to hide block of html that contains unity container inside. But when it shows again unity container reloads. But I don't want to each time unity is reloaded. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some browsing on the internet we didn't find a good solution. One of them was to set `left` and `position` css properties.

The problem was that hiding/showing part of html was performed with css property `display:none` and it seems that if you 'splice' html from the browser view with `display:none` (but not from DOM) and than 'inserts' it again unity perceives this as page reloading and performs container reload. seems that each time you load unity container it causes to be reloaded from unity scripts.

But now I've found that using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` does not perform unity reload! :)

So, if you are also stuck with the same problem, try to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`